# MySQL: same field value in multiple UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union

I use MySQL5.1 and I have a table where we log actions regarding jobs. Here is its schema definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `actions_log` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action` varchar(45) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
  `job_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `candidate_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I need to create a request builder so that users can search the table using "AND" and "OR" operators as well as parenthesis. The SQL request should return the candidate ids.
For example, they should be able to make the following search: "ActionA OR (ActionB AND ActionC)".

I used UNION clauses to achieve that and it does the job when a specific job is provided :

```
SELECT `candidate_id` FROM (
    SELECT `candidate_id` FROM `actions_log` WHERE `job_id` = 1858 AND `action` = 'a'  
    UNION DISTINCT                                                                            
    (                                                                                         
        SELECT `candidate_id` FROM (
            SELECT `candidate_id`, COUNT(`candidate_id`) AS `count` FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT `candidate_id` FROM `actions_log` WHERE `job_id` = 1858 AND `action` = 'b'
                UNION ALL                                                                                        
                SELECT DISTINCT `candidate_id` FROM `actions_log` WHERE `job_id` = 1858 AND `action` = 'c'
            ) AS level1
            GROUP BY `candidate_id`
        ) AS level2
        WHERE `count` = 2                                                                                                                              
    )                                                                                                           
) AS candidates;
```

Users can also search without specifying a job. In this case, any job should match.

That's where the problem is: action have to be for the same job to be valid result. 
For example, using the example above, having "ActionA" for job 1 and "(ActionB AND ActionC)" for job 2 should not be a valid match.

I could not find a way to make this work if the job is not specified. Maybe UNION clauses are not the way to go in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is enough:

```
SELECT candidate_id 
FROM actions_log AS a
WHERE job_id = 1858 
  AND ( action = 'a'  
     OR action = 'b' 
    AND EXISTS 
        ( SELECT candidate_id 
          FROM actions_log 
          WHERE job_id = a.job_id
            AND action = 'c'
        )
      ) ;
```

or if you want to have the conditions separated, so you can build more complex queries easier:

```
    SELECT candidate_id 
    FROM actions_log AS a
    WHERE job_id = 1858 
      AND action = 'a'  
UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT b.candidate_id 
    FROM actions_log AS b
      JOIN actions_log AS c
        ON  c.candidate_id = b.candidate_id
        AND c.job_id = b.job_id
    WHERE b.job_id = 1858 
      AND b.action = 'b'
      AND c.action = 'c' ;
```

Comment: The problem is when no job id is specified.

Comment: When no job is specified, remove the `job_id = 1858` condition(s).

Comment: My solution was overcomplicated. Yours is much simpler and does the job. Thanks!